# A property of Hermitian matrix and positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: matrices

Assume $\mathbf{Q}$ is a $N\times N$ Hermitian nonsingular matrix, and $\mathbf{A}$ is also a $N\times N$ matrix, does the following statement hold?
$$\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q} \succeq \mathbf{0} \Longleftrightarrow \mathbf{A} \succeq \mathbf{0}, \tag{1}$$
where $\succeq \mathbf{0}$ denotes the positive semi-definiteness.

I know the converse $\mathbf{A} \succeq \mathbf{0} \Longrightarrow \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q} \succeq \mathbf{0}$ is easy to prove by the definition of the semi-definiteness. However, is $$\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q} \succeq \mathbf{0} \Longrightarrow \mathbf{A} \succeq \mathbf{0} \tag{2}$$ correct? How to prove? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $B=QAQ$ then $Q^{-1}BQ^{-1}=A.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In fact, you can use the converse to prove the desired implication.

Of course, we'd need to use the fact that if $Q$ is Hermitian, then so is $Q^{-1}$.  However, taking this for granted, we'd be able to say that since $\mathbf{A} \succeq \mathbf{0} \Longrightarrow \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q} \succeq \mathbf{0}$, we have
$$
\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q} \succeq \mathbf{0}
\implies
\mathbf{Q}^{-1}(\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q})\mathbf{Q}^{-1} \succeq \mathbf{0}
\implies
\mathbf{A} \succeq \mathbf 0
$$
Note that the non-singularity of $Q$ is a necessary for this implication to hold.

**Proof that** $Q^* = Q^* \implies (Q^{-1})^* = Q^{-1}$:

Note that
$$
 Q^{-1}Q = QQ^{-1} = I = I^* = (QQ^{-1})^* = (Q^{-1})^*Q^* = (Q^{-1})^*Q \implies\\
Q^{-1}Q = (Q^{-1})^*Q
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another hint: [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia)

Congruence transformations preserve the inertia of a Hermitian matrix (the number of negative, zero, and positive eigenvalues). That is, if $X$ is a nonsingular matrix, a Hermitian $A$ has the same inertia as $XAX^*$. Also note, that $A\geq 0$ if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative. Plug your Hermitian $Q$ instead of $X$ and you have it.